# Missing toolbar menu from Processing Modeler QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

Does anyone know how to I may have turned off the algorithms and inputs tool menus in the modeler? I have not been able to figure out how to get it turned back on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this happened in your case, but I was able to make the panel disappear and reappear by using the "splitter". This is a thin vertical bar that usually separates the algorithms panel from the model panel. They can be quite difficult to see on some operating systems.

- Hover the mouse just to the left of the big white panel, just inside the window border, and the mouse pointer should turn into a two-way arrow cursor (<-> on Ubuntu)
- <kbd>Click</kbd>and <kbd>drag</kbd> the pointer to the right and once you've moved it far enough to the right, the panel should (hopefully) pop back.