# Missing toolbar and panel from graphical modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

Does anyone know how I can turn on the toolbars and panels of the QGIS 3 graphic modeler? I closed them and now I do not know how to enable them again, consequently only a blank window appears. I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 as operative system

[image]

Comment: May be this link can help you. 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/missing-toolbar-menu-from-processing-modeler-qgis